# starting new Gstreamer project on VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, video-streaming, gstreamer, qtgstreamer

cheers!

Im trying to open new project with visual studio 2010 
the version I want to use is 1.0.

so, those are the steps I used to do that:

```
1. installed windows DDK 7.1.0 
2. opened (I tried regular and gstreamer SDK) new project with VS-2010 
3. added x86.props (from C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\share\vs\2010\msvc) 
4. added gstreamer-1.0.props (from C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\share\vs\2010\libs) 
5. changed the working directory to "C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\bin" 
6. copied the basic code (Hello World) from here- [Hello World][1]
```

I did exactly the same thing but with 0.10  (and it worked) and now, with 1.0, when I build the code I get the  error:

Error   1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'gstreamer-1.0.lib'

after I added the "gstreamer-1.0.lib" (from C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86\lib) to "Additional Library Directories"

I got the error:

Error   1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcrt_winxp.obj'

I will be happy for some guidance of starting new gstreamer project..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `msvcrt_winxp.obj` is part of WinDDK, so it sounds like something has gone wrong with setting up your visual studio project.

First of all, make sure you're using the gstreamer packages from gstreamer.freedesktop.org and not the SDK from gstreamer.com. The SDK is for the older gstreamer 0.10.

Now having just said that, the gstreamer.com website still has some useful documentation on it. I recommend following the instructions at the bottom of this page, under the heading "Creating new projects using the wizard":
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Windows

You'll want to click to expand the manual installation instructions in the blue box, as the installer did not automatically copy all the files for me.

Once you've got that set up, make a new project using the wizard and everything should work!

If you're still having problems, check the instructions under "Remove the dependency with the Visual Studio runtime" to make sure you've installed the DDK properly.